# Working of Feed Readers in Web Applications

Tags: java, push-notification, rss, atom-feed

I wanted to know how RSS/ATOM Feeds work. Do the feed readers connect regularly to websites to fetch data or do the websites send data to the feed reader. Also how can i include a feed reader in my website. How would it work on the server side any rough idea would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSS is an XML format. Feed readers regularly connect to the address of the RSS feed and parse that XML file. I assume you are thinking about Google Reader, which uses AJAX to poll the RSS feed and see if there are any updates.

There are already many existing RSS frameworks for Java, including [Rome](http://rometools.org/).

Comment: Alright so the websites dont really push the data , instead feed readers from the client connect and check for updates ... is this correct ??

Comment: That's right. Google for RSS readers and you can find plenty of implementations. Clients regularly check an XML feed located at a URL for updates. Responsiveness of the client depends on how often they check the feed. In fact, if you click on a RSS feed directly, you will see the content feed in raw XML. You can write a client or find a plugin for your website.

Answer (score 0):

Check this website - http://www.whatisrss.com/ it explains most of your questions.  This website will explain you how to put rss feed on your website - http://webdesign.about.com/od/rss/a/rss_whats_new.htm.  There is a wide range of feed readers, if you want one for your website it would depend what technology you are most familiar with.  Then you can either look for one in this technology or try to code on your own.  Examples - http://www.labnol.org/internet/tools/embed-rss-feeds-add-html-websites-javascript/2515/, http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/

Hope it helps.